# Docker image for Debian : Access to the file or directory '/usr/local/openjdk-8/bin/java' is denied

Tags: java, docker, debian, gitlab-ci, permission-denied

While performing some Java related operation for Mendix on docker image "openjdk:8-jre" , I am getting an error: "System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the file or directory '/usr/local/openjdk-8/bin/java' is denied."

**Note:** Command I am executing is not being executed manually, but I am using Gitlab for CICD for my project and one of the script is executing this Java related command.

A bit about Mendix : This is a platform I used for building my app. I am trying to build a deployable package on this docker image using following command.

```
mono /modeler/mxbuild.exe --output="Automation" --java-home =$JAVA_HOME --java-exe-path=$JAVA_HOME/bin/java Automation.mpr
```

I tried to execute following two commands before executing java command:

```
su
chmod 777 $JAVA_HOME/bin/java
chown -R root:root $JAVA_HOME
```

Not able to figure out why permission is getting denied .

Comment: Can you start the container and shell into it? I am interested in the attributes of the /usr/local/openjdk-8/bin/ directory and /usr/local/openjdk-8/bin/java binary.

Comment: Yes. I am able to start the container and shell into it.Regrading attributes, I am simply executing some command related to Mendix tool. For this command, I have mentioned Java Home and Java Executable path.